# Access denied Please try to logout and sign in again. If this message persists, please contact the store owner

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-login, access

i getting the error "Access denied Please try to logout and sign in again. If this message persists, please contact the store owner." when i try to login in admin panel. i have no other username and password.I also tried to log out and login again but same problem. please tell me any solution.  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, that appears when you add a new user but you don't set good role:
https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-deal-with-access-denied-issue-in-admin-panel.html

In the table admin_role, do you have any row with 'Administrators' as role_name ?
You can update your database to put right role to your user (look the tables admin_role / admin_rule / admin_user). You can also create a new admin user with magerun if you have it installed.